# Place an order does not work on checkout/onepage/ after moving from 1.7 to ver 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento, payment, orders

Place an order does not work on checkout/onepage/ after moving from 1.7 to version 1.9.1 [ New ]
Options

54 seconds ago

I have upgraded from 1.7 to version 1.9.1. I have made many changes but nothing is working.

Luckly i manage to fix login page and update cart with few code change in id etc.

Anyone have any idea. i am realy stuck. :smileyhappy:

Wht changes i have made regarding placing an order so far

i have added this at the bottom of info.html

```
review = new Review('<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>', $('checkout-agreements'));
```

I also added this value in payment.phtml public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
```

getChildHtml('methods') ?>

but no luck. the page does not go anywhere at all. any idea!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Stuck with same problem :(

Answer (score 5):

To solve your checkout problem goto:

> /app/design/frontend/**base/default**/template/checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

Double check if you are using this file from base/default, might be overwritten in your current design package!

change:

```
<fieldset>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

to:

```
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I had same problem & what you pointed is absolutely right, because for me the store is working with main theme perfectly & i have the problem while switching to the another theme.But unfortunately your solution is not working :( . is there any way to debug ? what i observed is :when i click place Order button , A request is sent to saveOrder

Comment: can be nearly everything. try to adjust your themes template to the core templates logic. or if its a custom theme like ultimo etc. try to update and hope that your predecessor did a clean job.

Answer (score 0):

Thats what code look like please have a look and let me know if there is any error

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
<fieldset id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</fieldset>
```

and on bottom of page this code is

payment.currentMethod = "getChild('methods')->getSelectedMethodCode() ?>";

Also in another payment.phtml at /public_html/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage/ there is only devision used no fieldset so i have added id in div . can u check if this is right. thanks

```
<form action="" id="co-payment-form">
<div class="fieldset" id="checkout-payment-method-load">
    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('methods_additional', '', true, true) ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('methods') ?>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to this [guy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178304/onepage-checkout-stuck-on-billing-section) the issue ended up being related to the security update supee-9767.

The temporary solution he suggested was to go to:

```
System => Configuration => Admin => Security
```

and turning the `'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout'` setting off.

This worked for me after much hours of research.